# In SVG font family not getting updated?

Tags: svg

After trying a number of solutions, any of them didn't worked, please someone fully guide me, i don't know whats the problem with SVG and how to solve this. Here is the code where i want to change the family font of text:

```
<g id="Optimal_Scheduling">
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 288.4666 36.4608)">
    <tspan x="0" y="0" class="st2 st3">Optimal Scheduling</tspan>
    <tspan x="-8.3" y="27.6" class="st4 st2 st5">Create your resource-optimized </tspan>
    <tspan x="12.7" y="40.8" class="st4 st2 st5">schedule with one click</tspan>
  </text>
</g>
```

I want to change the text of "Optimal_sceduling", "Create your resource-optimized " and "schedule with one click".

Comment: What solutions did you try?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [ask] and update your question with a [mcve].